# Does @Valid work without @Validated on @RestController?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, bean-validation

In following blog entry.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation

The author mentioned about how Spring Boot works with `@Valid` annotation.

```java
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @PostMapping("/users")
    ResponseEntity<String> addUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {
        // persisting the user
        return ResponseEntity.ok("User is valid");
    }
    
    // standard constructors / other methods
    
}
```

> When Spring Boot finds an argument annotated with @Valid, it automatically bootstraps the default JSR 380 implementation — Hibernate Validator — and validates the argument.

Is it true that `@Valid` works as expected on `@RestController` without `@Validated`?

Then what kind of stereo types required to be explicitly annotated with `@Validated`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes `@Valid` will work without `@Validated` in `@RestController`.

> In Spring, we use JSR-303's @Valid annotation for method level
> validation. Moreover, we also use it to mark a member attribute for
> validation. However, this annotation doesn't support group validation.
> Groups help to limit the constraints applied during validation. One
> particular use case is UI wizards. Here, in the first step, we may
> have a certain sub-group of fields. In the subsequent step, there may
> be another group belonging to the same bean. Hence we need to apply
> constraints on these limited fields in each step, but @Valid doesn't
> support this. In this case, for group-level, we have to use Spring's
> @Validated, which is a variant of this JSR-303's @Valid.  This is used
> at the method-level. And for marking member attributes, we continue to
> use the @Valid annotation.

You can read more about this in this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-valid-vs-validated).

Comment: Will vice versa work? Only specify `@Validated` and no `@Valid` ?

Comment: No, not exactly. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Following minimal rules inferred by testing a `@RestController`:

1. A method parameter is validated if a `@Valid` annotation is present on the method parameter itself. The parameter type, i.e. class, itself has to be annotated by some validation constraints, but a `@Validated` on the class is not necessary.
2. Immediate validations like `@Min(1)` on method parameters require the `@Validated` annotation on the `@RestController` class itself. This comes in handy e.g. for `@PathVariable @Size(min = 1, max = 5) Long[] ids`

Comment: A very good, more elaborate reading on this topic: https://medium.com/javarevisited/are-you-using-valid-and-validated-annotations-wrong-b4a35ac1bca4